# Paginating a table in React-bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, pagination, react-bootstrap

I am trying to paginate a table using react-bootstrap. To do this I created a page below. However instead of seeing the pagination component in the docs, I see a bunch of `<li>` tags for "<<", "<" "1", "2", ">", ">>" on separate lines.

Also when I click the next button or a page button instead getting a number in the eventKey of my handleSelect I get the entire event object.  Looking around such as here: https://www.codereviewvideos.com/course/pagination-filtering-and-sorting/video/react-pagination-part-1 and https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#pagination, it seems react-bootstrap returns a number. In the example documentation all the list items have a href defined. However, my components do not, why does it not setup proper links for the page buttons?

-- Updates --
I need to download the styling from: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/customize/ to get the appropriate styling to work for .paginate and .paginate-md

Why does the react bootstrap styling and links fail for my case?

```
export default class MyPage extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        activePage: 1
    };
    this.handleSelect = this.handleSelect.bind(this);
}

handleSelect(eventKey) {
    console.log('handle select', eventKey);
    this.setState({
      activePage: eventKey,
    });
}

getPaginatedTable() {
    var dataRows = Globals.Data["dataList"]; 
    const totalPages = Math.ceil(dataRows.length/PER_PAGE_SIZE);
    var startOffset = (this.state.activePage-1) * PER_PAGE_SIZE;
    var startCount = 0;
    return (
        <div id="dataTableDiv">
            <table>
                <thead>
                   //mycolumns
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {   dataRows.map((dataRow, index) => {
                            if(index >= startOffset && startCount < PER_PAGE_SIZE){
                                startCount++;
                                return (<DataRowDisplay key={index} Data={data} />);
                            }
                        })
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <Pagination bsSize="medium"
                prev
                next
                first
                last
                ellipsis
                boundaryLinks
                items={totalPages}
                maxButtons={MAX_PAGE_SIZE}
                activePage={this.state.activePage}
                onSelect={this.handleSelect}
            />
        </div>
    );
}


render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {this.getPaginatedTable()}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: When I use your pagination, the Pagination component is not visible.

Comment: This type of pagination component is not supported by react-bootstrap now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2 issues were: 
1. ReactBootstrap styles weren't getting added in. 
2. The Pagination component wasn't generating the links for the pages correctly.

1. Needed to download and add the expected CSS from https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/customize/ or https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started.html#install stylesheets.
2. I was using an older version of the package needed to pull the latest NPM.